# TITAN : Gremlin query returns inconsistent results on repeated execution

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, rexster

I am running REXSTER/TITAN 0.4 over cassandra and uses gremlin for traversals.
I ran below gremlin query in Rexster Doghouse Gremlin console.

Vertex 92 was deleted earlier, since it was a duplicate vertex with same key ("eddy.com")

But when I am querying, I am getting that vertex sometimes, and sometimes not .
This is running in local dev machine, means no other threads or parallel task is running/updating this vertex in between.
Am I missing any configuration/settings here? is this a bug? please help!

```
gremlin> g.V('domain','eddy.com')

==>v[88]
gremlin> g.V('domain','eddy.com')

==>v[88]
==>v[92]
gremlin> g.V('domain','eddy.com')

==>v[88]
gremlin> g.V('domain','eddy.com')

==>v[88]
gremlin> g.V('domain','eddy.com')

==>v[88]
==>v[92]
```

Comment: Same problem here, i had runned deletion of each vertex with django/mogwai and get the same situation. HOW can i solve this?

Comment: @DmitryYudin Upgrade to latest version, this seems to be a bug

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say how your deletion occurred, but this issue almost always boils down to a uncommitted or stale transaction.  In other words, it's either:

1. The deleting transaction was not committed
2. The transaction was committed but the querying side did not start a new transaction and is thus getting cached data.

So, be sure to call `g.commit()` after you do you graph mutation.  Then, when you go to query (in a different context like Rexster Console, Dog House, etc.), be sure to `g.rollback()` before you query to ensure you aren't reading something stale.

If you're wondering why you would see the removed data in some cases and not others, it's because issuing a request to Rexster might get handled in a thread with a fresh transaction state (or not) giving you differing results.

On the chance that it is neither of these things and possibly a bug, I can only recommend that you update to Titan 0.5.4.