# I am getting previous versions for subsequent requests on same vertex using TitanDB

Tags: cassandra, titan, corruption

Hi I am querying the database for a specific vertex (any vertex) and I am getting different versions of the vertex. E.g fields have values based on updates I did in the past.. This might be related as it started happening after I switched from cassandra to cassandrathrift as backend in connection settings.

I am using a single machine (for development) with cassandra+elasticsearch. I would like to know if that is for sure that I have corrupted my database, what might have been the reason and how this can be prevented in the future for single machine development.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

I am getting this exception when I am trying to update a single vertex:

```
java.lang.Exception: failure in bulk execution:
[0]: index [titan], type [EntityTextFull], id [3aw], message [ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ]
[1]: index [titan], type [EntityTextFull2], id [3aw], message [ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.mutate(ElasticSearchIndex.java:614) ~[titan-es-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction$1.call(IndexTransaction.java:123) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction$1.call(IndexTransaction.java:120) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:56) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:42) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction.flushInternal(IndexTransaction.java:120) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction.commit(IndexTransaction.java:101) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.commitIndexes(BackendTransaction.java:125) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:732) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.TitanBlueprintsGraph$GraphTransaction.doCommit(TitanBlueprintsGraph.java:263) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.AbstractTransaction.commit(AbstractTransaction.java:94) [gremlin-core-3.0.1-incubating.jar:3.0.1-incubating]
    at com.xxxx.controllers.EntityController.updateEntity(EntityController.java:80) [EntityController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
14:06:43.295 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.t.t.g.database.StandardTitanGraph - Error while commiting index mutations for transaction [4] on index: search
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:44) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction.flushInternal(IndexTransaction.java:120) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction.commit(IndexTransaction.java:101) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.commitIndexes(BackendTransaction.java:125) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:732) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.tinkerpop.TitanBlueprintsGraph$GraphTransaction.doCommit(TitanBlueprintsGraph.java:263) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.AbstractTransaction.commit(AbstractTransaction.java:94) [gremlin-core-3.0.1-incubating.jar:3.0.1-incubating]
    at com.xxxx.controllers.EntityController.updateEntity(EntityController.java:80) [EntityController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Unknown exception while executing index operation
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.convert(ElasticSearchIndex.java:368) ~[titan-es-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.mutate(ElasticSearchIndex.java:620) ~[titan-es-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction$1.call(IndexTransaction.java:123) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.indexing.IndexTransaction$1.call(IndexTransaction.java:120) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:56) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:42) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: failure in bulk execution:
[0]: index [titan], type [EntityTextFull], id [3aw], message [ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ]
[1]: index [titan], type [EntityTextFull2], id [3aw], message [ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.mutate(ElasticSearchIndex.java:614) ~[titan-es-1.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328296/986160 which is an answer to similar issue - I added:
`graph.tx().rollback();` before I fetch data from the server (avoiding stale) and made sure I had `graph.tx().commit();` after I have mutated my graph.

This fixed my issue :)